# remote: Invalid username or password. fatal: Authentication failed, after two-factor authentication enabled

Tags: git, github, two-factor-authentication, multi-factor-authentication

After having enabled **two-factor authentication** I get the following error when attempting `git clone`, `git fetch`, etc:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/smartsendio/pickup-map.git/'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can not access using password after enable Two - factor authentication**

You need to create **Personal access tokens**
now use access token instead of password 
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After getting your access token you'll need to run one of the following commands. Then when you run your next 'git push' it'll ask you for your username and password, which is your access token.

MAC
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain

WINDOWS
git config --global credential.helper wincred

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to *use a personal access token*, as already described by @surendra; another solution is to **use a password-protected SSH key**:

Follow the instructions here:

https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.19/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

...but the essential point I want to make about authenticating with ssh is about the git config file, `.git/config` (inside your repo). You may see a line similar to the following:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/smartsendio/pickup-map.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Note the `url` line above... it must be changed to:

```
    url = git@github.com:smartsendio/pickup-map.git
```

...you can copy/paste the value from your GitHub repo's Code button:

[image]